# Is the JavaFX SimpleDoubleProperty.addListener method wrongly declared?

Tags: java, javafx

In my code, I am interested about listening to changes to a `SimpleDoubleProperty`.

Here's the signature for it's [addListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/DoublePropertyBase.html#addListener%28javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener%29) method:

```
public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super Number> listener)
```

How does a property that fires changes to a `Double` value, require it's listener to listen to `Number` or one of it's super types?. Shouldn't it be defined like that:

```
 public void addListener(ChangeListener<? extends Double> listener)
```

An example class that has the property:

**HasObservableProperty.java**

```
public class HasObservableProperty {
     private final SimpleDoubleProperty progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
     ...
     public void addProgressChangeListener(ChangeListener<? super Number> listener) {
         progress.addListener(listener);
     }
}
```

And so it goes, I have a listener defined as:

```
class ProgressBarNotifier implements ChangeListener<Number> {
    private final ProgressBar progress_bar;

    public ProgressBarNotifier(ProgressBar bar) {
        progress_bar = bar;
   }
   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> progress, Number oldValue,
                        Number newValue) {
        progress_bar.setProgress((Double)newValue);
   }
}
```

See how I was forced to cast the changed value to `Double`:

```
progress_bar.setProgress((Double)newValue);
```

This shouldn't be the case if the `addListener` method had the suggested signature.

So, the question is, is `SimpleDoubleProperty.addListener` method wrongly declared?

PS: what applies to SimpleDoubleProperty seems to apply to other observables, like [SimpleStringProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html).

Comment: I just noticed that the `addListener` method signature allows you to define a single listener for multiple events. But if this was the reasoning for it, does it really serve one of the main reasons of using generics, that to eliminate type casts?

Comment: I've been wondering the exact same thing as of yesterday.

Comment: I cannot see the relation between "progress.addListener(listener);" and "progress_bar.setProgress((Double)newValue);".

Comment: @UlukBiy The listener here is `ProgressBarNotifier`. When the property changes, it sets the value for the progress bar. Are we making progress here? :D

Comment: By the statement "This shouldn't be the case" I understood your question, in brief, as why does the Number newValue need to be casted to Double at progress_bar.setProgress()? Because setProgress takes a primitive double type and generics cannot work with primitive types, so you are actually doing auto(implicit) unboxing such as progress_bar.setProgress(newValue.doubleValue()); by down casting. Additionally, you are right about changelisteners signature for extending from Number, that allows defining multiple event types.

Comment: @ulukbiy My question is not why I need to cast. It's about why the method was defined in an awkward and counter-intuitive way. The way things stand now, you can't define a `ChangeListener<Double>` and add it to the property, which is most natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "because that's how it was done". Note that, as Uluk points out in the comments, you're not forced to cast: you can call `doubleValue()` on the `Number` reference you receive in the listener method.

There's a pretty complex hierarchy behind `DoubleProperty`. The relevant part is that `DoubleProperty implements ObservableDoubleValue extends ObservableNumberValue extends ObservableValue<Number>`. `ObservableValue<T>` defines an `addListener(ChangeListener<? super T>)` method, so `DoubleProperty` has to define `addListener(ChangeListener<? super Number>)`.

Was this the best way to do it? I actually don't think so: I **think** it would have been possible to make `ObservableNumberValue` generic: `ObservableNumberValue<T extends Number> extends ObservableValue<T>` and then `ObservableDoubleValue extends ObservableNumberValue<Double>`, at which point the `addListener(...)` method would be relaxed to `addListener(ChangeListener<? super Double>)`, which is what you're looking for.

There are whole other parts of the hierarchy: `Property`, `WritableDoubleValue`, `WritableNumberValue`, `WritableValue`, etc, that may prevent this structure; but at any rate such a change now would be impossible, so we are stuck with what we have whether it's a mistake or whether there's some complex reason it has to be this way that I'm not aware of. It's occasionally annoying, but as pointed out you can always use `doubleValue()`.

In many cases like the one you show, you can also use a binding, e.g. `progressBar.progressProperty().bind(progress);`